# Why does the common meaning of "impertinent" have nothing to do with "pertinent"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

Every time I want to use an antonym to "pertinent", I think of "impertinent", which I don't like to use because of its more common meaning.  How did "impertinent" come to mean "intrusive or presumptuous, as persons or their actions; insolently rude; uncivil" (Dictionary.com)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Etymology Online suggests that the use of *[impertinent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=impertinent&searchmode=none)* to mean "rudely bold" is connected to similar use in French, and happened around 1680.  It also offers the tantalizing tidbit

> especially by Molière, from notion of meddling with what is beyond one's proper sphere.

Now the first thing I think of when I see "Molière" is intermediate French class and the play *Le Bourgeois Gentilhomme*.  [Jean-Batiste Poquelin aka Molière](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moli%C3%A8re) was a French playwright whose satiric plays centered around characters who were taken out of their 'natural' element.  In *Le Bourgeois Gentilhomme*, for instance, is the story of a middle class man who aspires to the aristocracy.  He is like a fish out of water as he tries to learn to be a gentleman, and much hilarity ensues.

If we look closely at the etymology of the word, it is not too much of a stretch to equate "not pertaining to something" with "not a part of something."  The association with Molière's works certainly could have helped *impertinence* take on this slightly altered meaning.

So it would seem that the "intrusive or presumptuous" meaning of *impertinence* is fashionably French.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of *impertinent* are two:

- not showing proper respect; rude
- (formal) not pertinent to a particular matter; irrelevant

> Hers was an impertinent question.
>   Talk of *rhetoric* and *strategy* is impertinent to this process.

At least in the second case, *impertinent* is an antonym of *pertinent*.

The original meaning of the word is the second one; the meaning then slowly changed to the first one.

The Wiktionary has a note about the usage of *impertinent*:

> As many older speakers will consider definition 2 incorrect, avoiding the word altogether may be advisable. The construction "not pertinent" is one possible alternative.

Comment: I changed the question title.  Sorry I wasn't clear at first.  I didn't realize that "impertinent" ever meant "not pertinent"!

Comment: I wouldn't say the "irrelevant" sense of "impertinent" is *formal*. I'd say it's *archaic*. I really find it hard to imagine the word being used in that sense today, in any context.

Comment: The NOAD doesn't say that the second meaning is archaic and, as far as I know, it is still used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I did an edit.  See what you can make of it now!

Comment: @drm65: I'll not carp about the absence of my treasured word "archaic" in the answer! The substance is all there. Have a rep point on me! :)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: There will always be some misguided soul willing to defend our linguistic past, but I don't think you'll find many actual instances of the "irrelevant" sense in recent texts.

Comment: *I* am one of those misguided souls who is willing to defend our linguistic past, and even I don't think that using `impertinent` to mean "not pertinent" is a good idea.  I've literally *never* heard it used that way.  And there is no shortage of near-synonyms (`irrelevant`, `immaterial`, `superfluous`, `off-topic`, `diversionary`, and on and on), so let's just let that meaning go.  The original question is still open, though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Here are about 80 NGram hits for **impertinent to the matter**, 1950-2000 (a hundred years earlier there were many more). I haven't checked every single reference, but all the later ones seem to be just quoting earlier usage, not using it in earnest.

Comment: @Fumble If you want to dispute @kiamlaluno, why don't you post your own answer? Then you will have more room to discuss it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _Impertinent to the matter_ is not the only phrase where _impertinent_ could mean _not pertinent_. You are restricting the search, and you are probably leaving out relevant phrases.

Comment: @Kit: I don't have a problem with this answer in its current form. I have posted my own answer, simply to cover the morphic slide from *relevant* to *belonging* to *proper*. Not to discuss whether archaic usage persists in some unusual context I don't know of.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I am not infallible. Find a few contradictory examples and I will concede the point. It does occur to me that the Wiktionary entry may be misconstruing errors by non-native speakers as evidence of a revival of the archaic sense, but that's only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=pertinent):

> **impertinent**
>   late 14c., "unconnected, unrelated,"
>   from L.L. impertinentem (nom. impertinens) "not belonging," lit. "not to the point,"
>   from L. in- "not" (see in- (1)) + pertinens (see pertinent).

Sense of "rudely bold" is 1680s, probably modeled on similar use in French, especially by Molière, from notion of meddling with what is beyond one's proper sphere.

Answer (score 0):

"Pertinent" means "topical."

In its original form, "impertinent" meant "not topical," or in the language of this site, "off topic." That is actually an offense, because being "off topic" is widely seen as a form of "rudeness," or "lack of respect."

Over time, "impertinent" took on the connotations of "active," rather than "passive" rudeness. That is, it started to gain the meaning of outright disrespect (insolent or intrusive) as opposed to the milder "showing lack of respect" (rude or uncivil).